# How to count the units moved with 2 motor encoders

Tags: digital-logic

I have a 2 wheel device that both has motor encoders, counting the units moved on both motors is simple if the both motors speed is the same. My problem arises when the device is turning to the left or to the right. Turning causes one motor to speed up and the other to slow down. The count now on each motor is different.

Is there some logic or arithmetic i can apply that takes into accounts turnings? and can calculate the true distance moved of the device. The point of refence now of measuring the distance is now not on the wheel since it is not very reliable but now on the center of both wheels.

What I came up with is just to AVERAGE the left and right motor counts, but i do not know if this is the best solution to approach this problem

Any thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Seems reasonable. Why are your counts not whole integers, anyways?

Comment: Average is the only solution with this. Orientation 7.86/90 deg except for slippage

Comment: Average is a very poor solution to your problem. You have to do the math to do dead reckoning. Suggest you start with a simple approach using quadrature encoders ...this is a good starting point: http://www.seattlerobotics.org/encoder/200010/dead_reckoning_article.html

Comment: @DKNguyen It is not the count, its the distance, i just placed units instead of cm/inch.

Comment: @JackCreasey although it would be a nice feature to know the absolute posistion, my goals as of now is just the distance traveled. But i will keep in mind the link you gave me as future reference

Comment: i do suggest reading the first reference in that article http://rossum.sourceforge.net/papers/DiffSteer/DiffSteer.html

Comment: Just use diffeq to grab up a state space representation for the model/simulation (which you need) and then use a Kalman filter/error covariances observer of the motion. Done. It will just work. Period. There's ***nothing*** much good coming from simple averages. But feel free, of course.

Comment: @jonk this situation is an observable state and the Kalman gain from each variable would be exactly 0.5? and very predictable, so unlike integrating multiple G sensors, there is no need for Filtering et al.

Comment: One might consider a Kalman filter to figure out the liklihood of slippage after a complex trip and ending up in the same direction and determine the amount of slippage for other different conditions like excess torque or slippery roads but only after correlating direction with  another sensor not given.  But there is no problem here to demand such overkill unless it was known that the wheels are not parallel when turning. But still you need another sensor to correlate direction error.

Comment: If this had more than 2 driving wheels (eg 3, 4 ) then slippage error is  10 to 20x more likely.

Comment: For computing other variables beyond distance ...  http://www-personal.umich.edu/~johannb/Papers/pos96rep.pdf  In order to reduce slippage or gain error error , you need other sensors.

Comment: There are way lot of new terms for me im still slowly reading them all.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 As of now there are optical sensors in the systems.  I would like to add more odometry devices but space is fairly limited, im looking at  an inertial module since its already a really small ic, but i am not really sure if i will be able to utilize it

Comment: Is this for robot servo navigation?  What does optical sense? wheel encoder?

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 not a servo just an ordinary dc motor that has quadrature encoder attached to it, optical sensors that detects landmarks, and sometimes environmental ques.  Basically a mix of IR and color sensors

Comment: So what is the task? challenge?

Comment: traverse an area ( but not necessarily a maze) with obstacles ( obstacles are rearranged in every try) and there are somtimes cues in the are that will lead you closer to the goal, like a short line to follow perhaps, a color change in the area signifies you are getting closer, and some weird spefics like following a line with a certain length ( here will my question gets handy) and turn left/right means a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

### im not sure of my answer:

arc length = $$2\pi r\theta$$

[image]

distance between wheels = h

arc1 units = $$2\pi r\theta$$
arc2 units = $$2\pi (r+h)\theta$$

arc_center = $$2\pi (r+(h/2))\theta$$

### average:

$$(arc1 + arc2)  / 2 = (\pi\theta)(r+(r+h))$$
$$(arc1 + arc2)  / 2 = (\pi\theta)(2r+h))$$
$$(arc1 + arc2)  / 2 = (\pi\theta)(2(r+h/2)))$$
$$(arc1 + arc2)  / 2 = 2(\pi\theta)((r+h/2)))$$

you can see your method is actually = center arc length

Comment: centre is average of both wheels since they are always parallel

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 yes, this post is deriving that the center arc = average(arc1,arc2)

Comment: There is no other sensor input to determine slippage from lack of parallel wheels or center or  difference in centre of radius. Thus no other way to count. Of course one can average for velocity, acceleration etc. or do any complex math you want over any time interval but for position, there is no need.  In fact for all servo systems you want 1st order feedback when possible.

Comment: Robotic simulator software https://sourceforge.net/projects/rossum/
 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkanM.png